# Is there any way we can run multiple SQL queries at the same time in Athena Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-athena

I have to create 20 table in a Athena data base at the same time. Can I do it with a single execution.

example :

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.A 
; 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.B
;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.C
```

Comment: Please properly format the code snippet. Put 4 space characters in front of each instruction.

Comment: No you can't do that in a single execution. You would have to submit 20 separate queries

Answer (score 7):

I have used aws cli for such problems.
create a list of sqls.

```
sql_list.txt
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.A; 
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.B;
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS database_1.C;
----------
exec_sqls.sh
input_file=$1
while IFS= read -r sql
do
  echo "$line"
  aws athena start-query-execution --query-string "$sql" --result-configuration S3LocationForOutput=s3://<bucket>
done < "$input_file"
-----------
sh -x exec_sqls.sh sql_list.txt
```

Comment: this is perfect. I had to delete a bunch of tables, so I used SHOW TABLES, then pasted in my IDE and used the multi-cursor function to prepend a DROP TABLE IF EXISTS in front of each one, then used this script. Worked like a spell

Answer (score 2):

You can submit multiple requests simultaneously to Amazon Athena (eg via different threads in your application), but **each Amazon Athena command can only execute a single SQL query/command**.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar solution but using Redshift eternal tables and Dbeaver.
Changes made to external tables will be reflected automatically on Athena.

By using Dbeaver I'm able to run several DDLs on a single execution.
Minor changes are required:

- Update datatypes for each column from Athena to Redshift
- Update database name from Athena to Redshift's schema name
- Syntax to create partitioned tables. Only if applies